# What does "Notify" do?

Tags: discussion, email-notification

I want to know the exact functionality of the **Notify** checkbox below  the **Tags** field on the **Ask Question** page. How can I use it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

Each SE site sends ~daily emails with all replies to all questions you have notifications enabled at roughly 7am CEST(?).

If you visit the site regularly, you don't need them - their refresh rate is very long (up to 48 hrs), while other notification mechanisms like the StackEchange(tm) MultiCollider SuperDropdown (tm) are updated at every page refresh.